# Countif only half working on my spreadsheet

Tags: excel

Hi all so I am using the countif function to count the number of times a specific string appears in a spreadsheet. This formula works for 436 values out of 803 however for the remaining values it returns #VALUE!. Is there a way to fix this behaviour?
the formula I use is

`=COUNTIF(Table16[@[SRR accession]]:'BLASTx of viral contigs'!R1542,[@[SRR accession]])`

[image: Image of spreadsheet]

Comment: Could you show us the column and table headers  plz @Alex A so we can see which columns you're referring to? Also, is 'BLASTx of viral contigs' the name of the current sheet?

Comment: Please add a (copy of) your spreadsheet, not adding it as an image.